# How to clear the nested child routes when moving from one tab to another tab in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 application and I have child routes for the particular tabs.

I am trying that when the user moves from the child route of tab1 to the tab2 and when the user comes to the tab1, it should open the tab1 page not the child route of tab1.

This is **tabs.router.module.ts**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'eventdetails',
            loadChildren: '../eventdetails/eventdetails.module#EventdetailsPageModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'progresspage',
            loadChildren: '../myprogress/myprogress.module#MyprogressPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
     ]
    },
    {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
   }
  ];
```

When I move from the child route of any tab to the other tab, and when I move to that tab, it will open the child route from where I move to the other tab.

I want that when the user moves from the child route of any tab to the other tab and when it comes back to that tab, it should open that tab not the child one.

Like when the user moves from the tab1>progresspage to tab2 and when it clicks on the tab1, it should open the tab1 page not the progresspage page.

Any help is much appreciated.